# How to use JWT in Client with AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, jwt

My application is a Node.js API with a client inside the same application.

I'm trying to implement a simple auth login that uses a **JWT token** generated by a Node.js API.

My logic is as follows:

1. **Client**: User submits login information to `/auth/login` route.

```js
     $.ajax({
        url: "/auth/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (typeof data.redirect == "string") {
                window.location = data.redirect; 
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            if (typeof fail === "function") fail(data);
        }
    });
```

2. **API**: Verify user and on success generates JWT and sends back to the client.

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {

    var login = { UID: req.body.UID, password: req.body.password };
    AU.manualLogin(login)
        .then(result => {

            res.header("x-auth-token", result.token).json({
                status: 200,
                message: "success",
                data: result.data,
                redirect: "/dashboard" 
            });

        })
        .catch(err => next({ status: 400, message: err.message }));
});
```

3. **Client**: Saves JWT to the header and checks for `redirect` - In this case, I use `window.location` to direct to `/dashboard` after successful login. (this part I'm not sure about)
4. **API**: Middleware checks valid JWT on protected routes.

```js
module.exports = function auth(req, res, next) {

    const token = req.headers["x-auth-token"];
    if (!token)
        return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided.");

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "jwtPrivateKey");
        req.user = decoded;
        next(); //pass control to next middleware
    } catch (ex) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
    }
};
```

**The Problem:**

The token is definitely being sent from API -> Client. But I have no idea how to handle the token from the client-side. I think the issue might be to do with the `window.location` redirect as at this point it does not seem to be sending the `x-auth-token` to the API.

**What I have tried**

I have tested the solution with Postman from end-to-end and it works fine. That probably proves that it isn't the API side that has the issue.

I've also tried these sources:

- [Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)
- [Adding custom header in HTTP before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671199/adding-custom-header-in-http-before-redirect?rq=1)
- [How to add header to request in Jquery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929654/how-to-add-header-to-request-in-jquery-ajax)
- [jwt on node - how does the client pass the token back to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906102/jwt-on-node-how-does-the-client-pass-the-token-back-to-the-server)

Comment: I would suggest before redirecting, save the token in local storage or in a cookie

Comment: @DarkLord I've heard from multiple sources that saving to local storage or cookies isn't a good idea but then again I'm quite new to this still. Can it even be done without local storage and cookies?

Answer (score 1):

You need kind of a storage to keep the token. Otherwise the user has always to login again after he closes the browser/tab. So it's quite common to keep the token in **local** or **session storage**.

Approach 1: Use a single page application (SPA) framework like angular, vue.js, react etc. to protect your routes client-side

Approach 2: You can request only html and css (view) from your backend and then store the token after a login procedure. With a valid token, fetch the (protected) data with ajax requests. Redirect to the login page if a ajax request returns the status code 401 (unauthorized) or a user wants to access the protected route without having a token stored. This is perhaps the most suitable for you.

Approach 3: Use Node.js with a backend framework like express and store auth information in a server side session

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
app.use(require("cookie-parser")());
app.use(session({ secret: 'aslwezoweasdfasdlkfalksdfhweelaerfcv', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true}));
```

routes/protectedRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.all("/*", util.handleAuthenticate); // check auth on every request
// other routes
```

indexController.js (login functionality)

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    if(!req.session.name) {
        // check username/password --> db lookup
        // if valid:
        req.session.name  = ...
        // redirect to home or backref
        // else: redirect to login
    }
}
```

util/security.js

```
function isLoggedIn(req) {
    return !!req.session.name;
}

function handleAuthenticate(req, res, next) {
    if(isLoggedIn(req))
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
    // redirect to login page
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use that code into the initial request in number 1 (above) ? I tried adding this after but it didn’t work.